# Generic multiline macro with parameters

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to implement a generic stack in C, with the help of a big macro (not the best way, but that's not the point here). 
This macro contains functions declarations, structures and functions calls, with a `TYPE` type that would be replaced by what needed:

```
#define STACK(TYPE)                                                          \
(                                                                            \
    struct stack                                                             \
    {                                                                        \
        size_t           size;                                               \
        struct container *top;                                               \
    };                                                                       \
                                                                             \
    struct container                                                         \
    {                                                                        \
        TYPE             data;                                               \
        struct container *next;                                              \
    };                                                                       \
                                                                             \
    struct stack *stack_init(void)                                           \
    {                                                                        \
        struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof (struct stack));                     \
        if (!s)                                                              \
            return NULL;                                                     \
        return s;                                                            \
    }                                                                        \
    ... ...
)
```

This header file would be called in any .c file with this line

```
#include "utils_stack.h"
STACK(int)
```

Thing is, after trying every possible form of syntax gcc told me to try, I can't find a way to get it to work. I tried with parenthesis, brackets, both, none...
The code just simply won't work. Here is the error I get with the above syntax for example:
`error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’`

While trying to run gcc with the -E flag, I clearly see that `TYPE` is being replaced by `int`.

So here is my question, **How do I need to write my macro to be able to... use it ?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just get rid of the round brackets (i.e., the second and last lines), and it should compile without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, this should work, just remove the parentheses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define STACK(TYPE)                                                          \
    struct stack                                                             \
    {                                                                        \
        size_t           size;                                               \
        struct container *top;                                               \
    };                                                                       \
                                                                             \
    struct container                                                         \
    {                                                                        \
        TYPE             data;                                               \
        struct container *next;                                              \
    };                                                                       \
                                                                             \
    struct stack *stack_init(void)                                           \
    {                                                                        \
        struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof (struct stack));                     \
        if (!s)                                                              \
            return NULL;                                                     \
        return s;                                                            \
    }                                                                        \


STACK(int)

int main()
{
    struct stack *s;
    s = stack_init();
    // ...
}
```

Use parentheses if you define function-like macros, like:

```
 #define maxint(a,b) \
   ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

See [gcc statement expresions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) for details.

Comment: I tried that, and it returns me 
    `error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token`

(I did put it, that's why I don't understand)